# Can I remove newlines in a public key?

Tags: rsa, public-key, keys, encoding, ssh

Can I remove new lines from the RSA public key file to get a one line string? So the question is if the key looks like this

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

or

```
AAA\n\rBBB\n\rCCC\n\r
```

is this the same as

```
AAABBBCCC
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a base 64 encoded key file, since removing the newlines from a binary file would obviously break things.

The RSA standards (e.g. [RFC 2459](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459)) only define a binary representation for keys. In practice, like OpenPGP keys ([RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880)), they are often encoded in base 64 using the otherwise obsolete PEM standards ([RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421)).

The PEM printable encoding section says:

> To represent the encapsulated text of a PEM message, the encoding
> function's output is delimited into text lines (using local
> conventions), with each line except the last containing exactly 64
> printable characters and the final line containing 64 or fewer
> printable characters.

The OpenPGP radix 64 section says:

> The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more than 76 characters each.

For SSH, on the other hand, [RFC 4716 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716#section-3):

> A key file is a text file, containing a sequence of lines.  Each line
> in the file MUST NOT be longer than 72 8-bit bytes excluding line
> termination characters.

---

Do implementations in practice accept longer lines? I would expect many to do so. However, while no information is lost, it's technically nonconforming to use such encodings.

Comment: 4880 notes MIME 2405 which also says 76, not earlier 1421 which says 64; PGP & PEM have dashed BEGIN and END lines while MIME has other boundaries. More relevant to SSH is 4716, which cites all three but specifies different BEGIN/END lines and internal headers and max width 72. Unrelated but analogous, OpenSSL has many crypto 
primitives same as SSH and uses nominal PEM for many things; it writes 64 chars (per 1421), 
reads 76 chars (per 2405) in *most* cases and *silently drops* anything longer, although there has recently been discussion on the dev list about fixing this.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I missed the [tag:ssh] tag. If the question is specifically about SSH, 4716 is indeed most relevant.

Comment: Not sure why this Q showed active in 2019 but since it did: 'PEM' format was respecified -- still with lines broken at 64 -- by rfc7468 in 2015. OpenSSL 1.1.0 in 2016-08 up _does_ read lines longer than 76, but still not infinite. And not SSH format(s), of course.